# Disabling creature immune to mind affecting

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, immunities

I am playing an Artificer (Lv 5), focused on control spells/scrolls.

We recently ran through the following encounter:

Five creatures looking like zombies, immune to mind affecting spells (as all undead), with the ability to relocate themselves to a near unoccupied square (similar to the Dimension Door spell). The grafical rapresentation of this was them liquifying and reappearing at the desired spot.

The problem is, most of the scrolls I have with me are mind affecting (confusion, deep slumber, hold person...) or impede movement (web). This means that most of them would either not affect them or just make them move  to another unaffected square.

Are there better spell options to block the actions of creatures immune to mind affecting?

Comment: Are you looking for a way of bypassing Mind Effecting immunity, or are you just looking for alternative crowd control spells (e.g. Grease)?

Comment: I'm looking for alternative spells/methods to effectively lock down creatures. I'm not planning my build, so it's a bit too late to take particular feats/classes to bypass mind affecting resistances, and the problem is momentary, as I won't always be against immune creatures

Comment: Could you give us a bit more information about your build, such as class? Different casters will give us different spell lists and preparation methods to work with. :)

Comment: I wanted to keep it as a general question about effective spells against enemies immune to mind affecting, however I'll add a few details into the question.

Comment: This question really *is* specific to your situation, and there's no reason to be concerned that the question's too narrow; *narrow questions are good!* Your artificer doesn't *also* need to know, for example, how to knock unconscious a construct, but, instead, *really* needs to know how to impede zombies that possess this homebrew movement mode! Ask *that* question! Further, *any* information you can add about the special ability liquefy that the zombies possess will help narrow effects can be used to stop its use (particularly if you know the liquefy requires line of sight!).

Comment: @HeyICanChan I know absolutely nothing about that ability, only that it allows them to "teleport" to another square as a full round action, as I wrote in the question (it doesn't allow an attack afterwars, but they kept teleporting adiacent to us casters).

Comment: Are they also homebrewed to not be slow? Because normally it takes a zombie 2 rounds to perform a full-round action.

Comment: @topquark I don't know, they went down pretty quickly and never tried to move normally (as the few times they moved they always used that ability to relocate). They might as well be slow, and have that ability as a standard action. I could try asking my DM, but I don't know if I will get an answer, he may plan to use them again.

Comment: (FYI, the editor has a spot to put notes about what was changed. Those notes shouldn't be also added to the post itself—the post should contain only question information, with no editing information, edit notes, or markers.)

Comment: As you advence in levels, you will fid out that you should always have a plan B for such situations. Not all enemies will be effected by mind-effecting spells; even some enemies will not effected by any spell at all. You can focus on a speciality but you also must have something else at hand for such situations. RPG games are full of surprises.

Grease is a such great spell. Unintelligent creatures generally took the bait and fails to move effectively. Even teleporting creatues may find the suitable spot to teleport after a few wrong-location-teleports

Answer (score 4):

## You shall not pass.

[Halt Undead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/haltUndead.htm) would provide you a few rounds, holding up to three targets in their positions. You should definitely consider buying a scroll or two.

## Look at me, I am the master now!

Even though some of the creatures are immune to mind affecting spells there is usually another way to take control over them, so you can still keep your role in the party, as a controller. Even at your current level the undead creatures could be easily enthralled with the [Control Undead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/controlUndead.htm).

## Dealing with other types.

There are other equivalents of such spells for Constructs, Oozes, and Vermin, who have the same immunity, however some of these exist only as class' special abilities, feats and magic items. For example, to control constructs you could use a Rod of Construct Control, but there is no spell providing such effect. Part of them may be still inaccessible for you, until you will be able to use 6-th level scrolls.

Answer (score -1):

Without a source of divine intervention (f.e. command / rebuke undead), you are limited to spells that (physically) target objects and/or area's.

Illusions, charms, compulsions, etc. etc. are useless against Undead, Oozes, Constructs and other creatures that do not posses any intelligence.

A simple solution for these situations could be a wand of magic missiles. (Also, as I never encountered such creatures before, I'd (try to) start the encounter with detect magic if possible.)

Comment: Not my downvote, but many traditional illusions (those of the [figment](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/magicSchools.html#figment) subschool) are not mind-affecting. Using the spell [*silent image*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsS.html#silent-image) to create a wall can be an adequate (albeit temporary) solution to a zombie problem.